# create search button in c# & retrieve the image by button

Tags: c#, sql-server, function, search, button

i have this source , i want create a search button to 
find the id & name & date & very important ( **retrieve the image**) 
& 
another search button to find the name recorded between to date
such as 21/2/2012 & 1/3/2012
find all record between to date .

namespace _2015
{
    public partial class import : Form
    {
        public import()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void bt_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] imagebt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txt_ipath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imagebt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);




        string constring = "Data Source=SKYNET-PC;Initial Catalog=2015;Integrated Security=True";
        string Query = "insert into t_import (id,name,barwar,imgc)" + "values('" + this.t_id.Text + "','" + this.t_name.Text + "','"+this.dt1.Text+"',@IMG); ";
        SqlConnection condatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmddatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, condatabase);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            condatabase.Open();
            {

                cmddatabase.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG",imagebt));
                myreader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();


                MessageBox.Show("پاشەکەوت کرا");
                while (myreader.Read())
                {


                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source=SKYNET-PC;Initial Catalog=2015;Integrated Security=True";
        string Query = "update t_import set id='" + this.t_id.Text + "',name='" + this.t_name.Text + "' where id='"+this.t_id.Text+"' ; ";
        SqlConnection condatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmddatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, condatabase);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            condatabase.Open();
            {
                myreader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("بە سەرکەوتوویی نوێ کرایەوە");
                while (myreader.Read())
                {

            }
            }
        }
```

catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

`}
    }

    private void bt_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source=SKYNET-PC;Initial Catalog=2015;Integrated Security=True";
        string Query = "delete from t_import where id='" + this.t_id.Text + "' ; ";
        SqlConnection condatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmddatabase = new SqlCommand(Query, condatabase);
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            condatabase.Open();
            {
                myreader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("بە سەرکەوتوویی سردرایەوە");
                while (myreader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


        }
    }

    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.PNG)|*.png|All Files (*.*)|(*.*)";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string picpath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            txt_ipath.Text = picpath;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picpath;
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dt1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }`

}
    }

Comment: What specifically is the problem?  What is it not doing?  What exception are you getting and where are you getting it?  What results are being returned?

Comment: if i enter a name or id or date in the search button show result in the text boxes  and picturebox , if u look the pic do better                                              http://www.webchinupload.com/f/2015-04/b04b47689961c7f013e98414f4c6c596.jpg

Comment: @Source Like CindyH said its hard to determine your error without the error.  That being said NEVER concatenate SQL string this leaves you wide open to SQL injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and is something you should avoid at all costs.  Instead any variables should be declared as parameters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Are u trying to do scrapping of a web page from a Win Form, not clear what u want to do achieve? Describe your query in a proper manner...